# Is it possible to collect data from Firebase Analytics Console programmatically?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I would like to know if there is any way to collect data from Firebase Analytics Console programmatically in Android or Web?

I mean these data as you can see at pictures:

[image: Image1],
[image: Image2]

I am planning to do my own app to run my own analytics using these data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to collect the data from the Firebase **console**, however you can export the actual Firebase Analytics data to [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/) after which you can do anything you want with the data. See [BigQuery Export for Firebase](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7030014?hl=en).